# Jump to next above/below class declaration?

Tags: pycharm, shortcut, jetbrains-ide, keymaps

<kbd>Alt + Down</kbd> or <kbd>Alt + Up</kbd> will jump to next/previous  method relative to your current cursor position. Is there a similar functionality for jumping to the next above/below class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default keymap doesn't give the exact functionality you want. Cycling previous/next classes, like you cycle the methods, isn't possible. The closest thing is opening a list using <kbd>Ctrl+F12</kbd> with all the members in the module.

- Go to Settings <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+S</kbd> and [select `Keymap`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html).

  - In `Keymap` -> `Main Menu` -> `Navigate` there's <kbd>Ctrl+F12</kbd> that gives the list of objects in the file.
  - In `Keymap` -> `Main Menu` -> `Navigate` -> `Navigate in File` are the <kbd>Alt+Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+Down</kbd> shortcuts to cycle next/previous methods as you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this via IdeaVim plugin by adding this to `.ideavimrc` file (we use its search here):

```
nnoremap gU ?class <CR>
nnoremap [[ ?class <CR>
nnoremap ]] /class <CR>
```

`gU` takes you to the current class declaration. `[[`, `]]` for previous/next.